# Let's Encrypt with Traefik - JWS has an invalid anti-replay nonce

Tags: docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik

I have this composer file, it was working properly, but 2 days ago I added a new domain and it fails to get the Let's encrypt certficate,

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudns"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    labels:
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=false"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - "CLOUDNS_AUTH_ID=xxxx"
      - "CLOUDNS_AUTH_PASSWORD=xxxx"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: traefik
        target: /letsencrypt
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - "organic"

  php-apache:
    image: "php7.4"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    container_name: "php-apache"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.exampledomain.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.exampledomain.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.exampledomain.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=false"
    
    networks:
      - "organic"


networks:
  organic:
    driver: bridge
```

Here are the errors I'm getting

```
traefik       | time="2021-04-17T03:31:02Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] retry due to: acme: error: 400 :: POST ::  :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:badNonce :: JWS has an invalid anti-replay nonce: 

traefik       | time="2021-04-17T03:31:02Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"example.com\": unable to generate a certificate for thedomains [example.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[example.com] [example.com] acme: error presenting token: time limit exceeded: last error: %!w(<nil>)\n" providerName=myresolver.acme rule="Host(`example.com`)" routerName=exampledomain@docker
```

The tx is generated successfully in ClouDNS is normal, I have spent two days trying to figure out what might be the problem with no luck.

Comment: Do you need to add your resolver to the websecure entry point? In my config I have `"--entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certresolver=le"`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you mean there's a label in my config I should remove?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and after many configuration tries I deleted the traefik container (not recreate) as well as the letsencrypt volume. Then I redeployed with `docker-compose up -d`. On startup of traefik new certificates there generated immediately and without any complains. Hope this helps solves your issue as well.

```yaml
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: always
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik_proxy"   
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=tcp://docker-socket-proxy:2375"
      - "--ping=true"              
      - "--ping.entryPoint=ping" 
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=${CERTIFICATE_EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnsChallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,8.8.8.8:53"
      - "--entryPoints.ping.address=:8081"   
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"     
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"      
      - "--entrypoints.https.http.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "--entrypoints.https.http.tls.domains[0].main=${DOMAINNAME}"
      - "--entrypoints.https.http.tls.domains[0].sans=*.${DOMAINNAME}"   
    environment:
      - CF_DNS_API_TOKEN=${CLOUDFLARE_DNS_API_TOKEN}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "wget", "-c", "http://localhost:8081/ping"]
      retries: 3
      interval: "15s"
      timeout: "3s"
      start_period: "15s"
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
      - socket-proxy
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - "letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      #- "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true"
    depends_on:
      - docker-socket-proxy
```

Comment: Actually, I have done almost the same and it worked, very odd. should we create a ticket for it?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim I can't really reproduce it again so it will be hard to find a solution. But you can open an issue. Maybe the next who encounters it can add some additional details to the ticket.